# Retrieve all liked objects from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is it possible to get a list of *all* liked objects using the Graph API? I want to save a list of any articles (ie. items with URLs) the user has liked (say, in the past week). I've tried:

- `/me/likes` - this is liked pages only, not other items
- `/me/feed` - this is posts by the user only, not others
- `/me/home` - this might be possible, but seems to be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to get correctly, you can probably use the `/me/og.likes` Graph API endpoint. You'll need the user_likes permission for this.

The `/me/likes` endpoint returns Facebook Pages that the user likes, while the `/me/og.likes` endpoint returns any posts/links that the user has Liked (i.e. performed an Open Graph Like action on).

Comment: I tried that, and it seemed to work except I only got around 10 items. I think it was only returning publicly-shareable items?